# Is using else faster than returning value right away?

Tags: python, performance, if-statement, optimization, return

Which of the following is faster?

1.

```
def is_even(num: int):
    if num%2==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

2. 

```
def is_even(num: int):
    if num%2==0:
        return True
    return False
```

Regardless of which is faster, is there anything in PEP that states when to use one over the other (I couldn't find anything...)?

Comment: There should be no difference. Use the disassembler to see the generated code.

Comment: Even if you don't know how to disassemble, then couldn't you write some benchmarking code and compare the running times?

Comment: The language, in practice, will optimize these to be identical in performance -- but nothing in the specification requires it to, so anyone who writes code that _assumes_ they're going to be identical (or to assume that they're not) is wrong to do so, because they're relying on things the language spec does not guarantee. Anyhow -- do you have a _practical_ technical problem here? (Note the "actual problems you face" verbiage in https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the byte codes shown by `dis.dis()`.

`if/else` version:

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (num)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 BINARY_MODULO
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
              8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             10 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

  3          12 LOAD_CONST               3 (True)
             14 RETURN_VALUE

  5     >>   16 LOAD_CONST               4 (False)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

`if/return` version:

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (num)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 BINARY_MODULO
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
              8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             10 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

  3          12 LOAD_CONST               3 (True)
             14 RETURN_VALUE

  4     >>   16 LOAD_CONST               4 (False)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

They're idential up to byte 18. The `if/else` version has an extra 2 instructions to return `None` if neither of the blocks return from the function.

This is wasted memory, but won't affect the running time because both the `if` and `else` blocks *do* return. An optimizing compiler would realize that both `if` and `else` end with `return` so this isn't needed, but the Python compiler doesn't bother (apparently this has been fixed between Python 3.9.2 and 3.11.1).

Comment: What Python version did you use?  I got identical code with 3.11.1

Comment: I'm using 3.9.2